# show hidden div below current row of divs in responsive layout with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have a responsive layout for an image gallery that will show 3, 2 or 1 images per row based on user's screen width. here is the part of the CSS that will decide how many images to show per row:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
/* Smartphones: 1 image per row */
.box {
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 650px) and (min-width : 481px) {
/* Tablets: 2 images per row */
.box {
  width: 50%;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
}
}
@media only screen and (min-width : 651px) {
/* large screens: 3 images per row */
.box {
  width: 33.3%;
  padding-bottom: 33.3%;
}
}
```

for each ".box" div, there is another (initially hidden) div that should be displayed below the current row of images when tapping a button. this hidden div's width is always 100%, so it will fill one complete row.

on a desktop browser showing three images per row, it would look like this

```
    <div class="box">
        <div class="boxInner">
            <img src="../img/img1.jpg">
            <div class="infoBox">
                <button class="detailLink" name="det1">Show Details</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="boxInner">
            <img src="../img/img2.jpg">
            <div class="infoBox">
                <button class="detailLink" name="det2">Show Details</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="boxInner">
            <img src="../img/im3.jpg">
            <div class="infoBox">
                <button class="detailLink" name="det3">Show Details</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="detailWrapper" id="det1">
        <div class="detail">Details for img1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="detailWrapper" id="det2">
        <div class="detail">Details for img2</div>
    </div>
   <div class="detailWrapper" id="det3">
        <div class="detail">Details for img3</div>
    </div>
```

This is the script that will toggle the divs with details:

```
<script>
    $(".detailLink").click(function () {
      var id = $(this).attr("name");
      $("#"+id).slideToggle("slow");
    });
</script>
```

it looks like this now if the button for im1 is clicked:

http://postimg.org/image/b2tfnpwgn/

But if I resize the browser window so that only one or two images per row are displayed, obviously the initially hidden div for the first and second image will not be displayed below the first row anymore, but below the second row.

I have no idea how to rewrite this code so it will display the initially hidden div always in the row below the actual image, no matter if 1, 2 or 3 images are displayed per row. I could create three separate pages and redirect browsers to them based on screen width, but that seems somewhat redundant and there must be a better solution.

My first question on Stackoverflow - hope I did it right.

Comment: can't you just move the `.detailWrapper` inside the `.box`?

Comment: while the width of .box changes based on the amount of images to show per row, the .detailwrapper is always 100% wide - so in the example above the .detailwrapper has the width of 3 images. If I try to move it into the .box, I don't seem to be able to show the .detailwrapper below the current line in full width.

Comment: I see, I'm working in a solution for you, can I assume that you have a container element for each row of images? also what happens when you have 2 images per row? do you get  the next row with just 1 image?

Comment: No, there is no parent container for each row. Just a group of divs which get their width set based on the media queries I posted and will break onto a new row accordingly. So the approach you suggest would be to use JS to insert parent containers per row for each group of 1, 2 or 3 divs, based on screen width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need a javascript solution to rearrage your elements whenever the window is resized:

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NDWV9/7/show/)**

```
$(document).ready(function ()) {
    var $boxes = $('.box');

    $(window).resize(function () {
        //Get the css width of our elements to determine the media query breakpoint we're in
        var boxesWidth = $('.box').width() / $(window).width() * 100;

        if (boxesWidth > 50) { //One box per row
            $boxes.each(function () {
                var $detail = $('#' + $(this).find('.detailLink').attr('name'));
                //Move the detail after each box
                $(this).after($detail);
            });
        } else if (boxesWidth > 34) {//Two box per row
            $boxes.filter(':odd').each(function () {
                var index = $boxes.index($(this));
                var $details = $('.detailWrapper').slice(index - 1, index + 1);
                //Move details after the last box in row
                $(this).after($details);

            });
        } else {//Three box per row
            //Find the last boxes in row
            $boxes.filter(function (i) {
                return (i + 1) % 3 == 0;
            }).each(function () {
                var index = $boxes.index($(this));
                var $details = $('.detailWrapper').slice(index - 2, index + 1);
                //Move details after the last box in row
                $(this).after($details);
            });
        }
    });
    //Trigger resize event on page load
    $(window).resize();
});
```

Comment: Awesome! Based on your initial comment to my question I started fiddling with a similar approach, but only got half way through until you posted you solution. works just like intended, thanks!

Comment: There's one issue with this solution. It works great for 3 or 1 images per row, but not for 2 images. in your jsfiddle, make the browser window narrower so that only two images get displayed next to each other. You will see that the third and the sixth image will be in a row on their own now when the detailwrapper div is visible.

Comment: @theremin I see, for some reason I though that was the intended behavior but now that you mention it I doesn't seem right at all, I've updated my answer to fix it